# I have an issue validating this code. It all points to my closing html tag, but I can't figure out where the issue is

Tags: validation, xhtml, w3c-validation

This is a homework assignment.  The assignment is completed, but I just have to validate it.  Normally I just research the validation errors and fix them, but this time the errors all seem to point to my closing html or head tags and I don't see what is wrong with them.

**end tag for "script" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

"head" not finished but document ended

end tag for "head" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

"html" not finished but document ended

end tag for "html" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

missing marked section end**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
    function checkForNumber(fieldValue) {
        var numberCheck = isNaN(fieldValue);
        if (numberCheck == true) {
            window.alert("You must enter a numeric value!");
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    function confirmPassword() {
        if (document.forms[0].password_confirm.value
            != document.forms[0].password.value) {
            window.alert("You did not enter the same password!");
            document.forms[0].password.focus();
        }
    }
    function billAutomatically() {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].delivery.length; ++i) {
            if (document.forms[0].delivery[i].checked == true) {
                document.forms[0].delivery[i].checked == false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    function billByIssue() {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].autoRenew.length; ++i) {
            if (document.forms[0].autoRenew[i].checked == true) {
                document.forms[0].autoRenew[i].checked == false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    function sameShippingInfo() {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[5].checked == true) {
            document.forms[0].name_shipping.value = document.forms[0].name_billing.value;
            document.forms[0].address_shipping.value = document.forms[0].address_billing.value;
            document.forms[0].city_shipping.value = document.forms[0].city_billing.value;
            document.forms[0].state_shipping.value = document.forms[0].state_billing.value;
            document.forms[0].zip_shipping.value = document.forms[0].zip_billing.value;
        }
        else {
            document.forms[0].name_shipping.value ="";
            document.forms[0].address_shipping.value ="";
            document.forms[0].city_shipping.value ="";
            document.forms[0].state_shipping.value ="";
            document.forms[0].zip_shipping.value ="";
        }
    }
    function addJournal() {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[31].value == "")
            window.alert("You must enter a journal name.");
        else {
            if (document.forms[0].journals.options[0] && document.forms[0].journals.options[0].value == "none")
                document.forms[0].journals.options[0] = null;
            var journal = new Option();
            journal.text = document.forms[0].elements[31].value;
            journal.value = document.forms[0].elements[31].value;
            nextItem = document.forms[0].journals.length;
            document.forms[0].journals.options[nextItem] = journal;
            document.forms[0].elements[31].value = "";
        }
    }
    function deleteJournal() {
        var selectedItem = document.forms[0].journals.selectedIndex;
        if (selectedItem == -1)
            window.alert("You must select a journal name in the list.");
        else
            document.forms[0].journals.remove(selectedItem);
    }
    function changeJournal() {
        var selectedItem = document.forms[0].journals.selectedIndex;
        if (selectedItem == -1)
            window.alert("You must select a journal name in the list.");
        else {
            document.forms[0].journals.options[selectedItem].value = document.forms[0].elements[31].value;
            document.forms[0].journals.options[selectedItem].text = document.forms[0].elements[31].value;
         }
    }
    function confirmSubmit() {
        var submitForm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
        if (document.forms[0].name_billing.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].address_billing.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].city_billing.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].state_billing.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].zip_billing.value == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your shipping information.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.forms[0].area.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].exchange.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].phone.value == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter your telephone number.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.forms[0].userName.value == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter a user name.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (document.forms[0].password.value == ""
            || document.forms[0].password_confirm.value == "") {
            window.alert("You must enter a password.");
            return false;
        }
        var deliverySelected = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (document.forms[0].delivery[i].checked == true) {
                deliverySelected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
            if (document.forms[0].autoRenew[j].checked == true) {
                deliverySelected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (deliverySelected != true) {
            window.alert("You must select a delivery rate option.");
            return false;
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < document.forms[0].journals.length; ++k) {
            document.forms[0].journals.options[k].selected = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function confirmReset() {
        var resetForm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?");
        if (resetForm == true)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    /* ]] */
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Central Valley Technology</title>
<link href="cvtech.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="c9">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="c1" width="780">
        <tr>
            <td height="19" colspan="3">
                <img border="0" src="Images/cmpnylogo.gif" width="313" height="45" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <img border="0" src="Images/blckwhtstrp.gif" width="780" height="7" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c2" height="19" colspan="3" align="right">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="c1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img border="0" src="Images/cmpny.gif" width="58" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img border="0" src="Images/prds.gif" width="64" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img border="0" src="Images/srvc.gif" width="59" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img border="0" src="Images/chnprt.gif" width="110" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img border="0" src="Images/spprt.gif" width="54" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img border="0" src="Images/lgn.gif" width="95" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" height="4">
                <img border="0" src="Images/blustrp.gif" width="780" height="4" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="166">
                <img border="0" src="Images/smn1.jpg" width="265" height="166" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
            <td height="166">
                <img border="0" src="Images/smn2.jpg" width="255" height="166" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
            <td height="166">
                <img border="0" src="Images/smn3.jpg" width="260" height="166" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="35">
                <img border="0" src="Images/smn1a.jpg" width="265" height="35" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
            <td height="35">
                <img border="0" src="Images/smn2a.jpg" width="255" height="35" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
            <td height="35">
                <img border="0" src="Images/smn3a.jpg" width="260" height="35" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" height="31">
                <img border="0" src="Images/orngblckstrp.gif" width="780" height="31" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <img border="0" src="Images/grystrp.gif" width="780" height="7" alt="Visual formatting image" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="19" colspan="3">
            <div class="c10">
                <h1>Technology Journal Subscription</h1>
                <h2>Customer Information</h2>
                <form action="FormProcessor.html" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                      onsubmit="return confirmSubmit()";
                      onreset="return confirmReset()";>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="top">
                                <h3>
                                    Billing Information
                                </h3>
                                <p>
                                    Name<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name_billing"
                                           size="56" /></p>
                                <p>
                                    Address<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="address_billing"
                                           size="56" /></p>
                                <p> 
                                    City, State, Zip<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="city_billing" 
                                           size="34" />
                                    <input type="text" name="state_billing"
                                           size="2" maxlength="2" />
                                    <input type="text" name="zip_billing"
                                           size="10" maxlength="10" /></p>
                                <p><input type="checkbox" onclick="sameShippingInfo();" />Same shipping information</p>
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="top">
                                <h3>Shipping Information</h3>
                                <p>
                                    Name<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="name_shipping" size="56" />
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Address<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="address_shipping" size="56" />
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    City, State, Zip <br />
                                    <input type="text" name="city_shipping" size="34" />
                                    <input type="text" name="state_shipping" size="2" maxlength="2" />
                                    <input type="text" name="zip_shipping" size="10" maxlength="5" 
                                           onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);"/>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p>Telephone</p>
                    <p>
                        (<input type="text" name="area" size="3" maxlength="3" />)
                        (<input type="text" name="exchange" size="3" maxlength="3" />)
                        (<input type="text" name="phone" size="4" maxlength="4" 
                                onblur="return checkForNumber(this.value);"/>/>)
                    </p>
                    <p>User Name<br />
                    <input type="text" name="userName" size="50" /></p>
                    <p>Password <br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" size="50" /></p>
                    <p>Confirm Password<br />
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirm" size="50" onblur="confirmPassword();" /></p>
                    <h3>Delivery Rates</h3>
                    <table border="0">
                        <colgroup align="left" width="100" />
                        <colgroup span="4" align="center" width="100" />
                        <tr><th>6 issues</th>
                        <th>12 issues</th>
                        <th>18 issues</th>
                        <th>24 issues</th></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="17.50" onclick="billByIssue();"/>$17.50</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="26.95" onclick="billByIssue();"/>$26.95</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="32.90" onclick="billByIssue()"/>$32.90</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="delivery" value="46.00" onclick="billByIssue()"/>$46.00</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    <p>
                        <strong>Automatic Renewal</strong>:
                        <input type="radio" name="autoRenew" onclick="billAutomatically()" />
                        Monthly ($8.95)
                        <input type="radio" name="autoRenew" onclick="billAutomatically();" />
                        Yearly ($19.95)
                     </p>
                    <p>What technologies are you interested in?</p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="architecture" />Architecture <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="hardware" />Hardware <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="open_source" />Open source <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="data" />Data <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="windows" />Windows <br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="technologies" value="networking" />Networking <br />
                    </p>
                    <p>What is your job title?</p>
                    <p><select name="jobTitle">
                        <option value="itStaff">It Staff </option>
                        <option value="consultant">Technical Consultant </option>
                        <option value="integrator">Systems Integrator </option>
                        <option value="manager">Manager </option>
                        <option value="director">Director </option>
                        <option value="vp">Vice President </option>
                        <option value="seniorManagement">CIO, CTO, CSO, CEO, COO, Chairman, President </option>
                        <option value="other">Other </option>
                        </select></p>
                    <p>Journal <input type="text" size="68" /></p>
                    <p><input type="button" value="Add Journal" onclick="addJournal();" style="width: 120px" /></p>
                    <p><select name="journals" multiple="multiple" size="10" style="width: 500px">
                    <option value="none">Enter the technologies journals you subscribe</option>
                    </select></p>
                    <input type="button" value="Delete Journal" onclick="deleteJournal()" style="width: 120px" />
                    <input type="button" value="Clear List" onclick="document.forms[0].journals.options.length = 0;" style="width: 120px" />
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />&nbsp;
                    <input type="reset" />
                    <input type="button" value="Change Journal" onclick="changeJournal()" style="width: 120px" /></p>
                </form>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c5" height="19" colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at `/* ]] */`. What might be wrong there?

Comment: Also, technically the meta command for setting the charset is supposed to be in the first 512 bytes of the file.